Creating an excel from a dict while group values
(I'm very new to coding)
I'm trying to create an excel from a list of dictionaries, the excel should contain
name, email, location.
the dictionary has duplicates of names and emails but locations are one time only used.
i want to build an excel where the name and email have their own row but all the location where the names are used are assigned to a single name
the dict items look like this, and i have ~2000 of them.
dict_list=\[{'UserName': 'name', 'Email': 'email@email.com', 'location': 'x'}

end result should be
name | email@email.com | x ,y,c |

how should i build a list/dict that i can print to excel.
I've tried playing around with loop in a loop to check all the values against all the values of the second empty list, so if the entry doesn't exist, it copies it from the first one.
filtered_List = []
dict_list=[{'UserName': 'name', 'Email': 'email@email.com', 'location': 'x'}]
for user in dict_list:
    for filtered_users in filtered_List:
        if user['UserName'] == filtered_users['UserName']:
            filtered_users['location'].append(user['location'])
            continue
        else:
            filtered_List.append(user)
            break


One option is to use itertools.groupby.
import itertools

....

# groupby needs sorted data
dict_list.sort(key=lambda x: x["UserName"])

new_data = []
# Group by user name and email
for a,b in itertools.groupby(dict_list, key=lambda x: (x["UserName"], x["Email"])):
    user, email = a
    # Use list comprehension to join all the Locations
    new_data.append({"UserName": user, "Email": email, "Location": [x["Location"] for x in b]})

Using some randomly generated data, this produces
[
{'UserName': 'user1', 'Email': 'user1@example.com', 'Location': ['Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Philadelphia']}
{'UserName': 'user10', 'Email': 'user10@example.com', 'Location': ['Chicago']}
{'UserName': 'user2', 'Email': 'user2@example.com', 'Location': ['New York', 'Dallas', 'Houston']}
{'UserName': 'user3', 'Email': 'user3@example.com', 'Location': ['New York', 'San Jose']}
{'UserName': 'user4', 'Email': 'user4@example.com', 'Location': ['San Antonio', 'Dallas']}
{'UserName': 'user5', 'Email': 'user5@example.com', 'Location': ['Phoenix']}
{'UserName': 'user6', 'Email': 'user6@example.com', 'Location': ['Chicago', 'Los Angeles']}
{'UserName': 'user7', 'Email': 'user7@example.com', 'Location': ['San Jose', 'Philadelphia']}
{'UserName': 'user9', 'Email': 'user9@example.com', 'Location': ['Houston', 'Los Angeles']}
]


i keep getting
  6 user, email = a
  7 # Use list comprehension to join all the Locations

----> 8 new_data.append({"UserName": a, "Email": b[0]["Email"], "Location": [x["Location"] for x in b]})
10 print (new_data)
TypeError: 'itertools._grouper' object is not subscriptable

You need to convert it to a list (what I did originally) or see the updated code.

@ZilvinasDauknys Just noticed I didn't update part of the code. Try it now.

im confused, how did you convert to list?

b = list(b). But I edited the answer and removed the need to convert to a list. The current version of the answer works as expected.

what if i have a loop that  pulls data filters it and builds into this dictionary, how do change that it groups it to when it filters the data?
